# How to pass in '=' to a terminal command as is (Linux/macOS)?

Tags: linux, terminal

I am trying to run a program via its CLI. The command is something like this:

```
./Program -t -s -variables Param1=Value1,Param2="Value2=SubValue"
```

However, the Param2 is not accepted by the program. How can I pass in the "Value2=Subvalue" as is?

Comment: This is an issue with the CLI program itself or your usage of it, not the shell or terminal. So there's not much more to say, without knowing what that program is.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the program is parsing the command line arguments. My guess is that the program is setting Param1 equal to `Value1,Param2=Value2=SubValue`. Try a space between Param1 and Param2. What program is this? What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which command it's a bit difficult to know how it expects its parameters, but generally they are not separated by commas.  Try removing that and putting a space there instead.